# an algorithm in O(n) time complexity to find a pair of numbers in an array which have the closest difference between each other

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers which are not necessarily sorted, find a pair of numbers whose difference is least compared to any of the other pair of numbers in the array. the time efficiency should be O(n).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please post it... it would be a great starting point.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you cannot get a general linear time algorithm for this problem!

However, since you have (bounded) integers, you can cheat a little and start by sorting the array using radix sort, which is linear time! Then just find the closest adjacent pair, which is linear again.

Comment: In fact you can do it in constant time as basically just a breadth-first search in the line-graph of integers.

Comment: Technically this solution is O(N), since constants drop out.

Comment: Oh, just came up with a small proof outline that this problem is indeed in `O(n log n)` if you only rely on comparison: The "uniqueness" problem is well-known and in `O(n log n)`, and if this here problem was linear, you could also check uniqueness in linear time (the closest pair has a distance of 0) - QED.

Comment: @ltjax Except that you can use a hash table to determine uniqueness in O(n) amortized time.

Comment: @JohnKurlak: Yes, that's the same idea as the radix sort really. Only works with bounded integers though. For unbounded integers, you can always "break" hash functions.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the smallest absolute difference between any pair of distinct integers, then ltjax's algorithm will given you the answer in linear time. however, as the problem is stated negative numbers are valid; in that case, find the largest, L, and smallest, S, numbers using a linear search, then the answer is S - L.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may not wrong if I get first minimum element by Linear Search and then again apply loop to get second minimum element. for e.g.
min1=A[0];
for(i=0;iA[i])
         min1=A[i];
}
min2=A[1];
for(i=1;iA[i])
         min2=A[i];
}
diff=min2-min1;

Comment: false, consider the numbers 0, 2, 3; the two smallest are 0 and 2, but 3-2 is less than 2-0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find minimum two numbers and find the difference in this way.
index i pointing to 0, index j pointing to 1,
try to find min1 in even indexes via i, find min2 in odd indexes via j in single iteration and sub min1,min2.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of digits then apply radix sort O(n) in space and time